# Magento 2 module error after version upgrade

Tags: magento2, module, database, error, upgrade

I was recently trying to upgrade our Magento from 2.2.5 to Magento 2.2.7. I thought I succeeded but we're currently getting the following error:

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
>   disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 335576744754

Having looked at this var log  I can see the following message:

> {"0":"Please update your modules: Run \"composer install\" from the
>   Magento root directory.\nThe following modules are
>   outdated:\nAmazon_Core db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.1.2,
>   currently installed - 2.2.7\nAmazon_Core db data version: defined in
>   codebase - 2.1.2, currently installed - 2.2.7\nAmazon_Login db schema
>   version: defined in codebase - 2.1.1, currently installed -
>   2.2.7\nAmazon_Login db data version: defined in codebase - 2.1.1, currently installed - 2.2.7\nAmazon_Payment db schema version: defined
>   in codebase - 2.1.1, currently installed - 2.2.7\nAmazon_Payment db
>   data version: defined in codebase - 2.1.1, currently installed -
>   2.2.7\nKlarna_Core db schema version: defined in codebase - 4.5.2, currently installed - 4.5.6\nKlarna_Core db data version: defined in
>   codebase - 4.5.2, currently installed - 4.5.6\nKlarna_Ordermanagement
>   db schema version: defined in codebase - 4.4.1, currently installed -
>   4.4.2\nKlarna_Ordermanagement db data version: defined in codebase - 4.4.1, currently installed - 4.4.2\nKlarna_Kp db schema version: defined in codebase - 5.5.1, currently installed - 5.5.4\nKlarna_Kp db
>   data version: defined in codebase - 5.5.1, currently installed -
>   5.5.4","1":"#0 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121):
>   Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#1
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#2
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#3
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#4
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#5
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#6
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#7
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#8
>   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#9
>   {main}","url":"/admin_adminname/","script_name":"/index.php"}

I've logged into SSH and tried to run "Composer install" but it says there is nothing to update.

I've tried numerous other commands including:

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 bin/magento cache:clean
 php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Having looked in the "setup_module" table I can see that the versions in the table do not correspond with the versions in module manager as evidenced in the screenshot below

[image: Screenshot]

I could really use some advice if anyone knows how to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution to this, although it may not be conventional is to go to your websites database and find the setup_module table.

Find the modules that are causing the problems in the `module` column and change the `schema_version` and `data_version` columns appropriately.

Hope this helps.

You could also try having a look at your json.lock file, and changing the versions to what they should be and then deleting these modules and running `composer install`

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I'll look into that. I've uploaded a backup for now but obviously this is going to be an issue in the future. I'll continue to look into it.

Comment: Hi. Tried to update again. Same thing happened but changing these values in the database seems to have fixed it. Thanks again for posting this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says your codebase is behind your database recorded version.

```
The following modules are outdated:\nAmazon_Core db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.1.2, currently installed - 2.2.7\nAmazon_Core db data version: defined in
```

to remove the error, you need to tell your database that your versions are much earlier than this:
In this case, do get n98-magerun2 script (from [here](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2))

```
and run n98-magerun2.phar sys:setup:downgrade-versions
```

Now, my worries is that your database was updated at a time you had another codebase and maybe there is another underlying issue.. but for now, the above should sort you out.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying but I'm afraid that this has not resolved the problem.